# Different logo on different pages

Tags: 6

I want to switch my site logo for different pages. Actually there are two site logo's that need to appear on different set of pages on my drupal 6 website.

What is the easiest way of doing this? Is there any module available for doing this or some other easy steps??

Comment: What differentiates these pages?  Content type, taxonomy, Organic Groups?

Comment: I must strongly recommend that you don't implement anything that is "logo-specific", to solve this problem. You could use the [Logo tool](http://drupal.org/project/logotool) module as someone has suggested, but such super-localized modules are to be avoided in my opinion. If you instead wield good tools, such as [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context), or similar, you will learn to solve 100 _other_ problems while you solve this one.

Comment: I agree with you Latherion, but vies and panel contexts have been used by me only with ctools. Can views help in redering conditional site logo as per requirements???? Please tell me if you have any such experience. I would love to do it this way.

Comment: If it were me I'd ditch Logo and use a two different blocks that simply contain an image.  Configure one to show up on all pages except a few certain sections, and another block that shows up on those sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module appears to have helped many: [Logo Tool](http://drupal.org/project/logotool)

From the Logo Tool page:

> A simple tool to display either a random logo on every page refresh, else display a specific logo on specified pages and a default set logo on all unspecified ones.